# Does inserting the region in /etc/default/crda speed up wifi connection?

Tags: performance, connection

I noticed that with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS the wifi connection speed is lower than with the older version, significantly while using hotspot from smartphone, very very slow in upload.

I found on the web that in the file `/etc/default/crda` I can specify the country (e.g. `REGDOMAIN=IT`).

By doing so, it'll speed up my wifi connection?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Doubt it.

It is relevant for choosing permitted wireless channels as not all channels are permitted in all countries. In Europe we have channel 12 and 13. In the US those are not allowed.

The system will pick a correct channel anyways and stick to that. If it might speed up anything it is the initial connection and that is just a 1 time event in the whole process.

Comment: no good answer ... it does improve speeds

Comment: Proof it with an answer and I will remove mine. I doubt that ONLY changing the country is relevant for the speed.  The country setting should block channels so it will switch from a blocked channel to another. Sure but you can get the same result by only changing the channel.

Comment: This seems to indicate that Rinzwind is right: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/mcgrof/crda.git/tree/README  Key quote:  CRDA is no longer needed as of kernel v4.15 since commit 007f6c5e6eb45
    ("cfg80211: support loading regulatory database as firmware file") added
    support to use the kernel's firmware request API which looks for the
    firmware on /lib/firmware. Because of this CRDA is legacy software for
    older kernels.